# Wordpress Unknown Query

Tags: query

I have the following query and i can't find where is executed

```
SELECT count(ID) FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC;
```

Does anybody know where could be executed?

Comment: And how do you know that you "have that query"?

Comment: from the slow query log

Comment: What the heck is "slow query log"?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Ok... and _where_ and _how_ did you output it?

Answer (score 2):

It is not hard to log queries performed by WordPress. Simplest way would be to use plugin such as [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) that collects backtrace information about where in code was query performed.

Comment: i need to locate the page where is executed not to check all possible pages with debug bar

Comment: @user416096 unless you are doing some specific and varied coding in your pages, most of queries are usually part of load and do not differ much. I would suggest you at least try this for starters.

Comment: i have found all the slow queries in the code without the debug bar, but this one seems impossible to locate i'm using wp 3.1

Comment: Upgrade to wp 3.3, 3.1 is old and insecure

Comment: Debug bar should be able to tell you where the code is for that query, find the query using debugbar then look at its trace to see where it is being called from.

Answer (score 0):

If any tool/plugin doesn't help, open your favorite text/file editor, go for find text (usually <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>) and paste `SELECT count(ID) FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1` and find in all files i.e wordpress folder....... try with different combination which you think is specific with query in question....